# counting number of rows while skipping some based on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 that looks kind of like this:

```
ID   I1  I2 ...  IN
-------------------------
1    2   3  ..... 2
2    0   0  ..... 0 
3    2   1  ..... 5
```

Where IN is about 9 columns. What I need to do is count the number of rows, but skipping rows where the values of I1..IN are 0's. I'm new to SQL and I have basically something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Expr1, 
       COUNT(I1) AS Expr2, 
       COUNT(I2) AS Expr3, 
       COUNT(IN) AS ExprN 
 FROM [mytable] 
WHERE (Expr2 !=0) 
  AND (Expr3 != 0) 
  AND (ExprN != 0)
```

I imagine there is an easier and more efficient way of doing this? I need to ensure that all of the column entries are 0 (other than the ID). I would prefer not to rely on a single column being 0 or not to make the determination. I working with a database somebody already created and these 0's should have been NULLS.

Thanks!

Comment: I take it you're stuck with the zero rows? Because another way of dealing with it is to remove them if they are no longer needed.  Then it's a simple `count(*)` .

Comment: I thought about this, but I can't remove them as these non values are used elsewhere. I also thought about actually updating them all to be NULL, but I have not been able to verify that the 0 values aren't expected anywhere in the code base I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Expr1, 
       COUNT(I1) AS Expr2, 
       COUNT(I2) AS Expr3, 
       COUNT(IN) AS ExprN 
 FROM [mytable] 
WHERE (I1 + I2 + I3 + I4 + [... +] IN) <> 0
```

... but I'm still not sure this meets the problem you're trying to solve.  COUNT(I1) will return the same as COUNT(I2) because they'll be non-NULL in all the rows.  Are you trying to find the number of rows with non-zero values?

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Expr1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN I1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Expr2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN I2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Expr3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN IN = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as ExprN,
 FROM [mytable] 
WHERE (I1 + I2 + I3 + I4 + [... +] IN) <> 0
```

Comment: No, your first solution is what I am looking for. It is pretty much what I have except adding each of the I1..IN columns is syntactically easier. I just didn't know if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view on [mytable] which replaces the zeroes with nulls, and use that view for all future selects.  It would help you gradually transition the zero-to-null assumption into your code.

```
CREATE VIEW [myview]
AS
SELECT [ID],
    NULLIF(I1, 0) I1,
    NULLIF(I2, 0) I2,
    NULLIF([IN], 0) [IN]
FROM [mytable]
```

The question is, though, do you want to count the number of non-zero values in each column, or the number of rows with all zeros?

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(ID,I1,I2,[IN])) AS Expr1, 
       COUNT(I1) AS Expr2, 
       COUNT(I2) AS Expr3, 
       COUNT([IN]) AS ExprN 
 FROM [myview]
```

Expr1 will count the number of rows where **all** values are 0 or null, Expr2 will count the zeroes and nulls in I1, etc.  Note that in this case, each of the resulting columns can have different values.

Comment: This is a good idea. I went with just the straightforward approach, but I will need to come back to this at a later time. I think this would probably be a better long term solution until I figure out if I can safely replace or all together remove these rows.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `select count(*) from [mytable] where (i1<>0 and ... iN<>0)`

Comment: That will only return a single column, nothing like what's mentioned in the OP

Comment: This is what I am doing now. I'm looking for hopefully a more efficient solution as this feels hackish.

Comment: He did ask for a simpler version(!) =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CountOfRowsGreaterThanZero
FROM [mytable]
WHERE (I1>0) AND .... AND (IN>0)
```

As you're counting rows you shouldn't need to count each column as the number should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you mention, using NULLs solves your problem (because COUNT(X) only counts non-NULL values), then wrap your 0s with [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

Comment: I think I see. This would still require me to do this for every column I need though right?